# Get the difference between two DateTimes with microsecond precision

Tags: date, datetime, time, elixir

In Elixir, you can use `:calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1` to convert an Erlang time into the number of seconds since Epoch. The problem is, just with the number of seconds, you can't differentiate between two events which happened in the same second.

The `DateTime` struct, which my dates are instances of, *does* store the microseconds component of the date, but doesn't give me an easy way to find the difference between two times.

Does anybody know of a way (preferably without the use of a library) to find the difference, in microseconds, between two `DateTime`s?

Comment: Doesn't https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#diff/3 fit your needs?

Comment: It actually does. I saw it before, but didn't realise there was a third argument where I could specify `:microseconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `:microseconds` option to `DateTime.diff/3`

```
iex(1)> x1 = DateTime.utc_now()
#DateTime<2018-02-17 06:27:33.291406Z>

iex(2)> x2 = DateTime.utc_now()
#DateTime<2018-02-17 06:27:39.692571Z>

iex(3)> DateTime.diff(x2, x1, :microseconds)
6401165
```